# Beautifulsoup html parser sometimes strips plain ampersand symbol

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am currently setting up a data processing pipeline where survey answers are imported from a database. Some of the imported content is in HTML, which I need to strip consistently and convert to plain text, but the content is not 100% consistent. Specifically, special characters are sometimes unescaped and sometimes I get them as escaped HTML codes.

I've successfully been using beautifulsoup to achieve this, but now I've encountered an edge case where an unescaped ampersand is mysteriously stripped from the code.

For example, this code:

```
BeautifulSoup('R&D', features="html.parser").get_text()
```

results in:

```
'RD'
```

what I expect:

```
'R&D'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lxml` instead of `html.parser`

```
soup=BeautifulSoup('R&D', features="lxml").get_text()
print(soup)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and pray that it doesn't mess up in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

with html.parser - `In HTML, the ampersand character (“&”) declares the beginning of an entity reference (a special character). If you want one to appear in text on a web page you should use the encoded named entity “&amp;”`

So when it parses it without tags/as an entity, it will see that as a entity reference:

```
html = 'R&D'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

print (soup)
```

So gives output `RD`

However, if that is the content/text within the tag, it'll recognize the & as the encoded symbol:

```
html = '<span>R&D</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

print (soup)
```

Output is `<span>R&amp;D</span>`, so when you do `soup.text`, it'll correctly display `R&D`

Comment: This explains the behavior, but doesn't solve my problem, since I am dealing with inconsistent content that doesn't always have tags.

Comment: as stated in the solution below, you don't want to use the `html.parser`, but rather try the `lxml`